# Why "client.getState().getCookies()" always return zero length array?

Tags: java, php, cookies, httpclient

I use httpclient 3.0.1 to send a request to my php sever to get a cookie, and I get the

```
Set-Cookie: ResponseCookie=bbb
```

header string with

```
postMethod.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")
```

But the

```
client.getState().getCookies()
```

always return zero length array.

I have not use any CookieSpec to match and filter the cookies.

I will appreciate you if any help!

Comment: I studied the source code of httpclient, and found out why.

Comment: postMethod.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.IGNORE_COOKIES);
postMethod.setRequestHeader("Cookie", cookieStr);

//must reset cookie policy to default for the response header cookie parse    postMethod.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.DEFAULT);